# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails when creating product

Tags: magento-1.9, create-product

I have the following code to create a product, but when I try to do it it throws me this exception:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) ON DE), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_type_id`, `sku`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, '2017-09-11 18:54:40', '2017-09-11 18:54:40')
```

Here is my code:

```
$single = $return['response']['diffgrdiffgram']['NewDataSet']['Produtos']['0'];
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');    
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');


$attr = Mage::getModel('novapc_allnations/attr')->load(1, 'entity_id');

$attr = array(
$attr->getData('fabricante'),
$attr->getData('part_number'),
$attr->getData('ean'),
$attr->getData('garantia'),
$attr->getData('peso'),
$attr->getData('preco_revenda'),
$attr->getData('preco_sem_st'),
$attr->getData('ncm'),
$attr->getData('largura'),
$attr->getData('altura'),
$attr->getData('profundidade'),
$attr->getData('subst_tributaria'),
$attr->getData('origem_produto'));

$control = Mage::getStoreConfig('allnations/general/id_allnations', 
Mage::app()->getStore());
if ($control != 'sku' and $control == 'other') {
    $control = 
Mage::getStoreConfig('allnations/general/id_allnations_other', Mage::app()->getStore());
}

    $products->setName($single['DESCRICAO'])
    ->setDescription($single['DESCRTEC'])
    ->setShortDescription($single['DESCRICAO'])
    ->setAvailable($single['DISPONIVEL'])
    ->setStatus($single['ATIVO'])
    ->setSku($single['CODIGO'])
    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
    #->setAttributeSetId(9)
    ->setTypeId('simple')
    ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))
    ->setTaxClassId(4)
    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
    ->setPrice($single['PRECOREVENDA'])
    ->setWeight($single['PESOKG'])
    ->setStockData(array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
        'manage_stock' => 1,
        'min_sale_qty' => 1,
        'max_sale_qty' => 5,
        'is_in_stock'  => $single['DISPONIVEL'],
        'qty'          => $single['ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL']
    ));

$products->setData(array(
    $control    => $single['CODIGO'],
    $attr['0']  => $single['FABRICANTE'],
    $attr['1']  => $single['PARTNUMBER'],
    $attr['2']  => $single['EAN'],
    $attr['3']  => $single['GARANTIA'],
    $attr['4']  => $single['PESOKG'],
    $attr['6']  => $single['PRECOSEMST'],
    $attr['7']  => $single['NCM'],
    $attr['8']  => $single['LARGURA'],
    $attr['9']  => $single['ALTURA'],
    $attr['10'] => $single['PROFUNDIDADE'],
    $attr['11'] => $single['SUBSTTRIBUTARIA'],
    $attr['12'] => $single['ORIGEMPRODUTO']
));

$products->setStoreId(2);

# Pega a CATEGORIA e a SUBCATEGORIA
$mainCat = $single['CATEGORIA'];
$subCat = $single['SUBCATEGORIA'];

# Faz uma checagem para ver se a categoria e a sub-categoria são iguais,
# se forem, adiciona somente na principal, se não forem, adiciona nas duas
if ($mainCat == $subCat) {
    $filter = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('name', ['eq' => $mainCat])
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $filter = $filter->getFirstItem();

    $products->setCategoryIds($filter->getId());
} else {
    $filter = $category->getCollection()
       ->addAttributeToFilter('name', ['eq' => $mainCat])
       ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

      $filter = $filter->getFirstItem()
      ->getId();

        $subFilter = $category->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('name', ['eq' => $subCat])
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        $subFilter = $subFilter->getFirstItem()->getId();

        $products->setCategoryIds(array($filter, $subFilter));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I don't know why, but changing this:

```
$products->setAttributeSetId(4);
```

to this:

```
$products->setData([
    'attribute_set_id' => 4
]);
```

worked.

Of course, I soft-coded it:

```
'attribute_set_id' => $products->getDefaultAttributeSetId(),
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this method is commented on your code:

```
->setAttributeSetId(9)
```

The `attribute_set_id` is required for product creation. Also, check if the `attribute_set_id` you specified exists in `eav_attribute_set` table.

Comment: Uncommented it and stills throws same error with ID 1. I do have it in `eav_attribute_set`, but, for some reason, the attribute sets from id 1 to 8 are all named Default, the 9 is missing and from 10 onwards are customs. Dunno if that could be it

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten :

```
->setStoreId(1)
->setAttributeSetId(9) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
```

Comment: I did not. I have `->setStoreId(1)` after I set my $attr data. and `AttributeSetId` is commented, but I uncommented it and it still throws same error